# HSTS in Nginx: should the Strict-Transport-Security header be added in subdomain server blocks too?

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, http, http-headers

Let's take the following `nginx.conf` configuration file with `server` blocks for `example.com` and `subdomain.example.com`:

```
http {
    ...

    server {
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=off default_server;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }
    server {
        listen [::]:443 ipv6only=off ssl default_server;
        server_name example.com;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security
            "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
        ...
    }

    server {
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=off;
        server_name subdomain.example.com;
        return 301 https://subdomain.example.com$request_uri;
    }
    server {
        listen [::]:443 ipv6only=off ssl;
        server_name subdomain.example.com;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security
            "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload" always; # <-- again ???
        ...
    }
}
```

The `includeSubDomains` part of the header apparently tells the browser that the header applies to all subdomains as well.

However, if that browser were to visit `subdomain.example.com` before ever seeing `example.com`, that wouldn't be of any help, would it? So to cover for this scenario, I need to add the same `add_header` in all subdomain server blocks too ...right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct that it's better to have the HSTS `Strict-Transport-Security` header everywhere you need it to make sure a client gets it even if `sub.example.com` is accessed before `example.com` or if the cached HSTS information has expired.

The `includeSubDomains` flag affects all subdomains of where it's present. This means that `includeSubDomains` on `sub.example.com` takes effect on `*.sub.example.com` instead of `*.example.com`. (This is only natural as it would be bad if e.g. `example.co.uk` could affect `*.co.uk`.)

- If you don't use any `sub.sub.example.com` you could leave the `Strict-Transport-Security` header of your subdomains without this flag.
- `subA.example.com` can't protect `subB.example.com`.

Answer (score 5):

Correct. The includeSubdomains option is used to enforce https on all resources linked inside an html page served by the current domain.

Quoting https://www.nginx.com/blog/http-strict-transport-security-hsts-and-nginx/ :

> For example, the HTML response for https://www.example.com can include
>   a request to a resource from https://example.com, to make sure that
>   HSTS is set for all subdomains of example.com.

Also beware that if you add an `add_header` directive inside a location { } block, you also need to redefine `add_header Strict-Transport-Security ...` inside that block. Quoting again:

> NGINX configuration blocks inherit add_header directives from their
>   enclosing blocks, so you just need to place the add_header directive
>   in the top‑level server block. There’s one important exception: if a
>   block includes an add_header directive itself, it does not inherit
>   headers from enclosing blocks, and you need to redeclare all
>   add_header directives:

Comment: I have a file with STS and other similar security headers that I include inside each server.

Comment: that's my point: it's not enough. 
This is a corner case, it might not apply to you, but for other readers it might be relevant: if you have e.g. ```add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status``` inside a location {} block and you don't repeat ```add_header Strict-Transport-Security ...``` inside that location block, the ```add_header Strict-Transport-Security ...``` from the parent server {} block is *not inherited*!!